# Where can I find command line history file created by vncserver

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, redhat, vnc-server

Where is the path of history file that created by vncserver command line or desktop command line simulator?

I need command line history, but when you use a desktop command line, I can't find history file. Or if you use vncserver command line.

Os: CentOS 6

Comment: @MatthR3D It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document](http://www.realvnc.com/products/open/3.3.7/man/vncserver.html) contains a list of files created by VNC server. It says the following:

```
$HOME/.vnc/host:display#.log
    The log file for Xvnc and applications started in xstartup.
```

Your command line history file may also have some information (e.g. `$HOME/.bash_history`).